# LINQ query : Get all fields including Foreign keys

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have the following query to get results by inclusive dates:

```
var q = from x in db.TableX
                    where x.Timestamp.CompareTo(fromDate) >= 0
                       && x.Timestamp.CompareTo(toDate) <= 0
                    select x;
```

My TableX has more than one foreign key. However, when I debug I only see one of them extracted while all the other keys are null even though I see them in the DB correctly not being null and connected with IDs to their foreign tables.

```
 public class TableX
    {        
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string str1{ get; set; } 
        public Table2 t1{ get; set; }
        public Table3 t2{ get; set; }
        public Table4 t3{ get; set; }
        public Table5 t4{ get; set; }
        public Tablet5 t5{ get; set; } 
        }
```

Comment: can you post your TableX class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinse you are using lazy loading you need to define navigation properties as virtual,and you need to enable proxy creation so that EF can create a proxy around your class and override those properties to load when required.

```
public class TableX
    {        
        public  int Id { get; set; }
        public string str1{ get; set; } 
        public virtual Table2 t1{ get; set; }
        public virtual Table3 t2{ get; set; }
        public virtual  Table4 t3{ get; set; }
        public virtual Table5 t4{ get; set; }
        public virtual Tablet5 t5{ get; set; } 
     }
```

Comment: Is Lazy loading the default? How can I change that?

Comment: `db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;` ah great !

Comment: http://codetuner.blogspot.com/2011/07/entity-framework-differed-loading-lazy.html Here is more info.